# Hibernate HQL and inheritance

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, hql

Here is my question -

There are two classes `Order` and `PaymentType`. An order will have one `PaymentType`. Now `PaymentType` is an abstract class and there are other two classes called `CreditCardPaymentType` and `PaypalPaymentType` which extends `PaymentType` class. In hibernate they are modeled as Single_Table strategy. `CreditCardPaymentType` contains a field called `CreditCardNumber`. I am writing following HQL and my intention is to eagerly load the `CreditCardNumber` entity.

```
session.createQuery("select order from Order as order " +
                "inner join fetch order.paymentType.Unknown");
```

What should come in place of "Unknown"? Since `PaymentType` class doesn't know anything about `CrediCardNumber` class, what can I put in the above query to eagerly load `CreditCardNumber`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do doesn't work anyway.

In Order you can't make an entity of type PaymentType and load it with hibernate. PaymentType is abstract and as consequence it can't be instanciated. Hibernate needs a constructor when loading the entity from so database. So you can't map abstract classes, you only can map implementing classes which have at least a parameterless constructor.

=> In the mapping of `Order` you have to specify if `order.paymentType` is `CreditCardPaymentType` or `PaypalPaymentType`. And that solves your problem, because then you know what `unknown` really is.

To solve your task: At database side you can continue with all payment types in one table. At Java side you have two possibilities (both meant as an idea):

1. You make PaymentType not abstract, with two methods `boolean isCreditCardPayment()` and `boolean isPaypalCardPayment()`, and PaymentType contains all columns of the database table. You only use this class and you forget the classes `PaypalPaymentType` and `CreditCardPaymentType`.

or

1. In the mapping of both `PaypalPaymentType` and `CreditCardPaymentType` you put a where condition ensuring only the rows for the correct payment type are loaded. In Order you drop the property paymentType and as a replacement you add two properties paypalPaymentType and creditcardPaymentType, which are referencing to the two Java classes. When loading the `Order`, one of the two properties will be null. For convenience you can make a method `PaymentType getPaymentType()`, which returns the not null payment type, but this convenience method you can't use in HQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

Please correct me if I am wrong. Check bellow code

```
session.createQuery("from Order as order " +
"inner join fetch order.paymentType.class = CreditCardPaymentType");
```

As per the [url](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html),

The special property class accesses the discriminator value of an instance in the case of polymorphic persistence. A Java class name embedded in the where clause will be translated to its discriminator value.   from Cat cat where `cat.class = DomesticCat`